# Why does Tableau LOD calcs display a range of values rather than a sum-total?

Tags: tableau-api

I get this problem often where I have a LOD calculation but instead of a single total value, I get the high and lows of the data range.

Here is my LOD calc:

[image]

But, the numbers it displays is a range of the lowest value to the highest value.  I do not understand this.  I have this problem often.

[image]

Comment: This may be obvious, but first ask yourself does this situation really require an LOD calc. People often use them when a normal simple calc would do, adding complexity and hard coding the calc unnecessarily for one particular view or task. From the little you posted, it is hard to see why this needs an LOD in the first place. Similarly, I agree with the others that a FIXED LOD calc is usually simpler to reason about and is usually the place to start if your situation requires an LOD calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I tend to deal with this situation is to wrap the calculation in WINDOW_SUM().

```
WINDOW_SUM(SUM([LOD Period Demand]))
```

Put the window_sum calc on the Detail shelf, where you'll be able to add it to the title for your summary.

Comment: Perfect.  I tried the sum([LOD] and the Window_sum([LOD]  but I hadn't combined them.  Thank you... Works now.

Answer (score 2):

If i interpret it correct, then your DemandSalesNet is at the level of Site, Whse and Period. Means unique on these three variables. Correct?

Try Using **"Fixed"** instead of using **"Include"**.
I hope that will work.

Comment: Yes... I have tried Fixed and Include... can having a hierarchy in the columns affect how LOD reads the data?

Comment: The DemandSalesNet actually extends down to a couple levels below Site/Whse/Period/Item....  So, since Item is a displayed column, I used a Fixed LOD to keep the sum at Site/Whse/Period... in the worksheet header.

Comment: I think I tried Include is because the worksheet is filtered.  I understand Fixed will sum up everything--not just what's showing.  There's where I'm trying to get is to only show the sum of what is showing, if that makes sense.

Comment: No, hierarchy have no significance. Can you please tell me on which field and what you want to filter?